# jQuery - Filtering data-attributes hides all elements

Tags: jquery

I'm filtering list-items with data-attributes using an input check box.

When a specific input item is checked all the elements gets hidden, even if they are not related to the checked value.

**Here's my jQuery Code:**

```
jQuery(document).ready(function () {

    //start filter
    jQuery('.cs-widget-content').delegate('input[type=checkbox]', 'change', function() {

    var lis = jQuery('.five-column > li.column');
    var checked = jQuery('input:checked');
            if (checked.length)
                    {                           
                        var selector = '';
                        jQuery(checked).each(function(index, element){                            
                            selector += "[data-offer~='" + element.id + "']";                            
                        });                        
                        lis.hide();                        
                        jQuery('.five-column > li.column').filter(selector).show();            
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        lis.show();
                    }
            }); //end filter

});
```

Here's the [**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/qqswmnyd/2/)

**Solution I'm looking for**

How to make this filtration work properly, all the items should be visible on page load, but when an input value is checked, only show those items. hide everything else.

Comment: so what is your question then?

Comment: Just a note - Which jQuery version are you using? As of jQuery 1.7, `.delegate()` has been superseded by the `.on()` method.

Comment: seems you hide all li's first then show the <li> related to the checked checkbox, I think this will never work since jquery runs async, it does not have the knowledge of which comes first, so the hiding/showing takes place at the same time, and probably the hiding finishes last in the race condition. you may do a hack by placing a delay of execution in the showing of the <li> via setTimeout

Comment: @Vucko i'm using jQuery 2.1.3

Comment: You have a typo in your fiddle's markup (`date-offer` instead of `data-offer`)

Comment: @CodingEnthusiast just updated my question

Comment: @billyonecan this is pretty embarrassing for me :( i have updated my fiddle

Comment: @DexterHuinda please take a look at this now http://jsfiddle.net/qqswmnyd/2/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/BramVanroy/qqswmnyd/7/

```
$(".cs-widget-content").on("change", "input[type=checkbox]", function () {
    $(".five-column > li.column").hide();
    $(".cs-widget-content").find("input:checked").each(function (i, el) {
        $(".five-column > li.column").filter('[data-offer="' + el.id + '"]').show();
    });
});
```

---

Or if you want to show the items that are *not* checked: http://jsfiddle.net/BramVanroy/qqswmnyd/8/

```
$(".cs-widget-content").on("change", "input[type=checkbox]", function () {
    $(".five-column > li.column").hide();
    $(".cs-widget-content").find("input:not(:checked)").each(function (i, el) {
        $(".five-column > li.column").filter('[data-offer="' + el.id + '"]').show();
    });
});
```

Comment: This is great... could it be possible that i show all the items on load and then filter it?

Comment: wow ... This is it..:) your jQuery is perfect just one more thing if you don't mind. When input is unchecked the items should show right?

Comment: Thanks for the answer, i have some other needs to change this function, i guess i should ask it separately.

Answer (score 1):

I changed your code a little bit to check the inputs on page load to show the users that what they are viewing is the default selection. If this compromises anything it can be changed.

See the [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qqswmnyd/6/).

Here's my JavaScript

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        $('input[type=checkbox]').prop('checked', true);    
});

$('input[type=checkbox]').on('click', function(){
    var self = this;
    var status =  $(self).attr('id');
    var selElements = $('ul.five-column > li.column').filter(function(){
        return $(this).data("price") == status || $(this).data('offer') == status;
    });
    if (self.checked) {
        selElements.show();
    }  
    else {
        selElements.hide();
    }
});
```

Comment: inputs should not be checked by themselves. user will do that

Answer (score 0):

Try substituting `data-offer` for `date-offer` at `html`

```
jQuery(document).ready(function () {    
    //start filter
    jQuery('input[type=checkbox]')
    .on('change', function (e) {
        jQuery('.five-column > li.column[data-offer]').hide();
        jQuery('input[type=checkbox]:checked').each(function (i, elem) {    
            jQuery('.five-column > li.column[data-offer=' + elem.id + ']')
                .show()
        });
    }); //end filter

});
```

jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/qqswmnyd/5/

Comment: it was a typo in my data-attribute code, that i have updated in my question. its `data-offer`

Answer (score -1):

change your code

FROM

...

```
lis.hide();                        
jQuery('.five-column > li.column').filter(selector).show();
```

...

TO
...

```
lis.hide();                        
setTimeout(function() {
   jQuery('.five-column > li.column').filter(selector).show()
}, 1000); // force a 1 sec delay before execution
```

...

Comment: its working.. but the delay makes the bad impression on layout. any other possibility? or show some kind of loading div?